# Arch Linux - switch from KDEmod to LXDE

Tags: arch-linux, lxde

How could I switch to [LXDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE) because it loads [KDEmod](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDEmod) at start?
(LXDE is installed like the wiki say ...)

Also, how could all KDE packages be removed easily afterwards without breaking something that I need?

Comment: do you use a login manager?

Comment: surely kdm for now but I will switch to slim ...

Answer (score 1):

> How could I switch to LXDE because it loads KDEmod at start? (LXDE is installed like the wiki say ...)

I would take a look at */etc/rc.conf* for what concerns the boot-up daemons (*slim* in place of *kdm*, for instance)

> Also, how could all KDE packages be removed easily afterwards without breaking something that I need?

This could be really hard to achieve, depending on what are your needs (for example, it will be difficult to remove **every** *KDE* file if you use [Konqueror](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konqueror), [Kate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kate_%28text_editor%29), [Konversation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konversation) and [K3b](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K3b)): anyway you could be interested in this REMOVE option:

```
*-u, --unneeded*
```

as well as this SYNC option

> *-c, --clean*

Hope that helps. :D

Comment: K-3D is not a KDE application, despite the name.

Comment: Yes, I know, but that was a typo: I meant k3b, the "KDE Burn Baby Burn" suite.

Comment: edit: corrected text and link